# PowerShell script to read columns of a list in all sitecollections of a farm

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

I have a list name like my contacts list in all the site collections of my farm,I need a report which tell me which all site collection have my contacts list with column name **"help"**.

Answer (score 0):

Open powershell ISE as admin and copy/paste script. 
Change names of list and column.

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $listName = "My Contacts" # < Enter your list name
    $fieldName = "Help" # < Enter your field name

    $fieldCount =$Null
    foreach ($site in get-spsite){ 
    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs){ 
    foreach ($list in $web.lists){

        if($list.Title -eq $listName){    
            $field = $Null
            $field = $list.Fields[$fieldName]

                if($field){
                $fieldCount++
              Write-Host "Field Name -$fieldName- found in: " $site.url - $web.Title - $list.Title  -foreground green           
                } 
           }                    

    }
    }
    }
        Write-Host "Number of times field Name -$fieldName- found: $fieldCount" -foreground Yellow
```

**EDIT**

if you need to log that in file use this script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$logfile = "C:\FieldNameLog_$(get-date -format `"yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt`").txt" #< change path and name
function log($string, $color)
{
   if ($Color -eq $null) {$color = "white"}
   write-host $string -foregroundcolor $color
   $string | out-file -Filepath $logfile -append
}

$listName = "My Contacts" # < Enter your list name
$fieldName = "Help" # < Enter your field name

$fieldCount =$Null
log "Field Name '$fieldName' found in:" darkyellow
foreach ($site in get-spsite){ 
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs){ 
foreach ($list in $web.lists){

    if($list.Title -eq $listName){    
        $field = $Null
        $field = $list.Fields[$fieldName]

            if($field){
            $fieldCount++
       log   "$fieldCount. $site - $web - $list "  green           
            } 
       }                    

}
}
}
    log "Number of times field Name -$fieldName- found: $fieldCount"  Yellow
```